# Using Timex Interval

Tags: elixir, timex

I've got

```
Interval.new(from: start_date, until: end_date)
```

with 
`[start_date, end_date] = [~N[2019-02-12 00:00:00.000000, ~N[2019-02-15 00:00:00.000000]`

The problem is, this generates the dates:

```
[~N[2019-02-12 00:00:00.000000], ~N[2019-02-13 00:00:00.000000],
 ~N[2019-02-14 00:00:00.000000]]
```

but misses the last day (15th Feb). Is there a way I can coax Timex to adding that boundary to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Timex.Interval.new/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.Interval.html#new/1) has a perfect documentation that clearly mentions `right_open: true` parameter.

---

The documentation is not quite accurate though :) It should be `right_open: false` FWIW.

```rb
[start_date, end_date] =
  [~N[2019-02-12 00:00:00.000000], ~N[2019-02-15 00:00:00.000000]]

Timex.Interval.new(
  from: start_date, until: end_date,
  left_open: false, right_open: false
)
|> Enum.to_list
#⇒ [~N[2019-02-12 00:00:00.000000], ~N[2019-02-13 00:00:00.000000],
#   ~N[2019-02-14 00:00:00.000000], ~N[2019-02-15 00:00:00.000000]]
```

Comment: I actually already tried this, I wouldn't have asked otherwise. I've ended up doing:             (Interval.new(from: start_date, until: end_date, right_open: true) |> Enum.to_list ) ++ [end_date]

Comment: Very much appreciate your help btw, Elixir is a truly wonderful language, I commend your efforts to help promote it.

Comment: That's it, thank you! :) It does look like the doc is a bit confusing! Thanks so much for your help! :)